# How to pitch modulate with a delay plugin

Tags: pitch, modulation

How can you modulate the pitch of a clip with a delay plugin?

Do you use the feedback?

Answer (score 2):

you use a lot of feedback and very small time interval (from 1 to 10 ms). like this :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

well, indeed you'll get a pitched sound using very shorts delay with a lot of feedback.. but if you want to do some pitch modulation out of a delay, you need to modulate the delay line. if you are on a modular environment (reaktor, max, etc.) try to patch a control signal (envelope generator, lfo) to a delayed signal.